# When I compare the growth rate of two functions, should I say Exponentially or Logarithmically?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Consider I have two functions: $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = \log(x)$, should I say "$g(x)$ grows logarithmically slower than $f(x)$ when $x$ increases" or "$g(x)$ grows exponentially slower than $f(x)$ when $x$ increases"?

Update:

Some background of the problem:

There is an existing algorithm of time complexity $f(x)$. I improve it and propose a new algorithm with new time complexity $g(x) = \log(f(x))$. When I describe my result, what is a good way to say $g(x)$ is better than $f(x)$?

Comment: $g(x)$ has logarithmic growth, or $f(x)$ grows exponentially faster than $g(x)$. Note that these aren't mathematically defined terms - so they are used in a sort of 'loose' sense. You could of course define your own version of 'exponentially faster' using big-oh notation or limits.

Comment: @Kaind Thanks for the suggestion! I have updated the question to add some background. $f(x)$ is something old, and $g(x)$ is the new thing so I want to say $g(x)$ is how much faster than $f(x)$.

Comment: Yeah, then $g(x)$ is exponentially better than $f(x)$.